# IE11 doesn't render my angularjs app on refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm working with an  AngularJS app v1.5.8, it works fine in chrome and firefox. But when I go to IE11, the first time it loads, it works fine, but if the user refreshes the site, it won't render.

I disabled the cache, I disabled compatibility mode and I added the meta tags that force IE11 to use edge, but nothing happens.

I opened the developer tools and I saw the network tab, everything seems to be arriving from the server just fine.

The console does not show any error message.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean angularjs 1.x right? because i had similar problems with angular2...

Comment: Yes, sorry,  AngularJS v1.5.8